# SELECT using timestamp in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, timestamp

my problem is trying to use a SELECT statement and order the top 10 by a certain column. I managed to compile something after searching through lots of forums, however I need to confirm that the timestamp in one field is within the last week. I have gotten this to execute however i'm not sure whether this is correct as I can't print the value for the where clause:

```
SELECT itemid, count(itemid) 
FROM Rateddate 
WHERE TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - DATE_RATED) < TO_CHAR(7)  
GROUP BY itemid;
```

TLDR:

```
TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - DATE_RATED) < TO_CHAR(7)
```

does this make sure the date_rated timestamp is less than a week old?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would make more sense to say

```
WHERE date_rated > sysdate - interval '7' day
```

if you want data from the last 168 hours.  You may want

```
WHERE date_rated > trunc(sysdate) - interval '7' day
```

if you want data from any point in the day 7 days ago rather than caring about what time of day it is currently.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work for you:

```
  trunc(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - DATE_RATED) < 7
```

This is assuming that `DATE_RATED` is a date field.  If not, you need to convert it first with `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: this throws ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: If this is a timestamp filed then you need to cast to a date. What is your table definition?